# C++ deque while reading data and storing as a class. error while initializing

Tags: c++, class, file-io, deque

I am reading a file and making my own class to store in a deque. Like this

```
class point{
  public:

  void setX(float n)
  {
       x = n;
  }       

  void setY(float m)
  {
       x = m;
  }          
  float x;
  float y;           
};

int main(){

ifstream file("curveData.txt");

float x;
float y;    
deque<point> dqu;
point tempPt;

while(file >> x >> y){
           cout << x << ' ' << y << endl;
           tempPt.setX(x);
           tempPt.setY(y);
           cout << tempPt.x << ' ' << tempPt.y << endl;
           // to check it was initialized correctly
           cout<<endl;
           dqu.push_back(tempPt);
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Inside the while loop the first cout displays the right value however after initializing the values of x and y of tempPt when I try to display the values are not initialized correctly. The y values are stored in TempPt.x and y value is some weird number which is same for all points.. What am I missing. Sorry I am new to C++.

Comment: Why bother with set functions? Just do `file >> tempPt.x >> tempPt.y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is inside setY(). It should contain

```
y = m;
```